# wordpress theme switching raises widgets error

Tags: mobile, widget, wordpress-theming

I am creating two themes for a wordpress site. One for desktop users and one for mobile users. I am using a simple plugin ("Mobile theme switch") to detect the mobile devices and switch to mobile theme.

I have registered some widgets area in the mobile theme to put some links with images in footer area.

Also assigned the widgets to those widget areas by activating the mobile theme.

When i activate the desktop theme and open the site in the mobile device, mobile theme is activated but footer widgets does not appear.

Does any body know how to solve this issue?

An other thing i noticed, when i activate the mobile theme from admin panel and open the site in the mobile device, it works fine and show the footer widgets.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code of that plugin to switch the theme.

```
add_filter('stylesheet', 'getTemplateStyle');
add_filter('template', 'getTemplateStyle');

function getTemplateStyle(){
    $mobiletheme =  get_option('mobiletheme');
    $themes = get_themes();
    foreach ($themes as $theme_data) {
      if ($theme_data['Name'] == $mobiletheme) {
          return $theme_data['Stylesheet'];
      }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what the issue could be without seeing the code. How does the plugin switch themes?  Does it allow you to place modules separately per theme?

Comment: Here is the link of that plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-theme-switcher/

Comment: Looks like a plugin bug: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-mobile-theme-switch-switcher-working-but-still-loading-headerfooter-from-desktop-theme